# std::max with a dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic, standard-library

I'm trying to use the std libraries as much as possible and I have a question with std::max

```
#include <algorithm>

void foo(size_t elem)
{
  auto testArray = new double[elem];
  for(int i = 0; i < elem; ++i)
  {
    testArray[i] = i;
  }

  auto maxElem = std::max(testArray, testArray + (elem - 1));
  delete[] testArray;
}
```

What is the best way to pass in the arguments to the std::max function here? I was hoping I could make this array behave like an iterator with a template.

Comment: It should be `testArray + elem`, not `testArray + (elem - 1)`.

Comment: I tried it with + elem and I got some unexpected behavior. It kept picking the last element each time and it was not the largest but it was the most negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `max_element()`, not `max()`.

```
auto maxElem = *(std::max_element(testArray, testArray + elem));
```